# Fields in Stable Homotopy Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, homotopy-theory

So, I believe that, given a ring spectrum $R$ and an $R$-module $A$, we say that $A$ is "free" if $A\simeq \vee_IR$, i.e. some indexed wedge of copies of $R$.  Now, as far as I understand, we can consider a ring spectrum $F$ a "field" if every $F$-module is free (do we need the wedge to be finite?).

I believe that a large class of examples of such fields are the Morava K-theories for a given prime, $K(n)$.  Are the Morava $K$-theories the only "fields"?  Specifically, do the Morava K-theories contain every Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum $\mathbb{H}F$ for $F$ a field?

If not, is there some other general classification of the fields in brave new algebra?

Many thanks to you!

Edit: One other thought. Is there a correspondence between $K(n)$ at a prime $p$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?  This is a total guess and completely unsubstantiated, but it would make sense I guess....

Comment: $H\mathbb R$ is a field but not a Morava k-theory. Moreover, The coefficient ring of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces is concentrated in degree zero whereas the coefficient ring of Morava K-theories $K(n)$ is not even bounded below if $n\neq 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commented reply is essentially the only counterexample.  In fact, if you set $K(0) = H\mathbb{Q}$ and $K(\infty) = H\mathbb{F}_p$ (which is quite reasonable if you view the $K(n)$ as built from the $E(n)$ and $P(n)$ spectra), then you get the following:

[Hopkins-Smith, Nilpotence in Stable Homotopy Theory II, Prop. 1.9]: For $E$ a field (in your sense), there is a prime $p$ and $n \in [0, \infty]$ for which $E$ is a wedge of suspensions of $K(n)$.